# Webpack: NextJS: Generate only hash classname

Tags: webpack, next.js

What I am using : NextJS and CSS Modules [.css]

What I am trying to Achieve :
`<div class="33ohh"></div>` or something similar to this.

What I am getting :

`<div class="video_thumbnails__33ohh"></div>`

My current Webpack config :

```
  x instanceof RegExp &&
  y instanceof RegExp &&
  x.source === y.source &&
  x.global === y.global &&
  x.ignoreCase === y.ignoreCase &&
  x.multiline === y.multiline;

module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    const cssRules = config.module.rules
      .find((rule) => typeof rule.oneOf === "object")
      .oneOf.find(
        (rule) =>
          rule.sideEffects === false && regexEqual(rule.test, /\.module\.css$/)
      );

    cssRules.use = cssRules.use.map((rule) =>
      rule.loader.includes("css-loader/dist")
        ? {
            ...rule,
            options: {
              ...rule.options,
              modules: {
                ...rule.modules,
                localIdentName: "[hash:base64:5]",
              },
            },
          }
        : rule
    );

    return config;
  },
};
```

I don't know what is wrong in my above code, kindly suggest and any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: For webpack 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744765/edit-css-loaders-localidentname-in-nextjs-to-hide-class-names-from-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix :

I was using Windows, had to change :

`rule.loader.includes("css-loader/dist/cjs.js")`

to

`rule.loader.includes("css-loader\\dist\\cjs.js")`